# How to save setMovable (of Toolbars) in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, toolbar

How does one store the `setMoveable` property of toolbars in Qt?

I am using `QSettings` and `saveState()` to save the states (e.g. positions) of toolbars. But apparently this does not save the `setMoveable` properties.

Here is the code for the loading and saving so far:

```
void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
    QSettings settings(QCoreApplication::organizationName(), QCoreApplication::applicationName());
    const QByteArray geometry = settings.value("geometry", QByteArray()).toByteArray();
    const QByteArray windowState = settings.value("windowstate", QByteArray()).toByteArray();
    if (geometry.isEmpty()) {
        const QRect availableGeometry = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(this);
        resize(availableGeometry.width() / 3, availableGeometry.height() / 2);
        move((availableGeometry.width() - width()) / 2,
             (availableGeometry.height() - height()) / 2);
    } else {
        restoreGeometry(geometry);
    }
    if (!windowState.isEmpty()) {
        restoreState(windowState);
    }
}

void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
    QSettings settings(QCoreApplication::organizationName(), QCoreApplication::applicationName());
    settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
    settings.setValue("windowState", saveState());
}
```

Comment: Do your toolbars have object names? Are another options remembered?

Comment: Yes, they have names and other oprions are remembered.

Comment: Please file a bug report for this, as it looks like a silly bug...

Comment: @peppe Done so @ https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54665

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to store them by yourself, using something like

```
QSettings settings(...);
settings.setValue("movable", toolbar->isMovable());
```

and

```
toolbar->setMovable(settings.value("movable", false).toBool());
```

respectively, assuming that there is a `QToolbar` like

```
QToolbar *toolbar;
```

Note that you can also use somthing like groups here

```
settings.beginGroup("QToolbar");
// access settings here (store/load)
settings.endGroup();
```

which helps in grouping the settings.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to replace `QToolbar` by a particular toolbar, like `fileToolBar`. And then do the saving/reading for each toolbar or does it save the state of all toolbars somehow? I tried `settings.setValue("movable", fileToolBar.isMovable());` but get a `C:\Users\Daniel\qt\application\mainwindow.cpp:374: error: C2228: left of '.isMovable' must have class/struct/union` and `C:\Users\Daniel\qt\application\mainwindow.cpp:374: error: C2660: 'QSettings::setValue': function does not take 1 arguments`.

Comment: @Daniel First your asumption is correct. Note that the second error results from the first so take a look that the variable `fileToolBar` is a `QToolBar` and accessible in the context.

Comment: Saving with `settings.setValue("movable", fileToolBar->isMovable());` and loading with `fileToolBar->setMovable(settings.value("movable", false).toBool());` works. Is that just my particular setup or do you want to edit your answer?

Comment: @Daniel That is very specific because the variable name could be anything. I edit another way.

Comment: @Daniel edited. Now I see your error better, because there was some irritation using dot operator. Thanks.

Comment: And I need to add the `.toBool()` as well. Otherwise I get a `C:\Users\Daniel\qt\application\mainwindow.cpp:364: error: C2664: 'void QToolBar::setMovable(bool)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'QVariant' to 'bool'`. You might want to add that as well.